# Push onto template data

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone view that looks like:

```
var BooksView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
   this.model.fetch({
      success : function(model, resp, opt) {
         var data = { model, navigationText: this.navText };

         this.$el.append ( JST['templates/' + "book"] ( data.toJSON() ) );

      }.bind(this)
   });
}

});
```

Basically, I'm trying to pass template data with model data, as well as other data that ISN'T model data. Right now, I can do:

```
this.$el.append ( JST['templates/' + "book"] ( model.toJSON() ) );
```

and it will send the model data. But for example, I have a variable (navigationText) I want to pass to the template as well, but it shouldn't ever be model.set.

With my current code, I get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`, because it's not a valid object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't JavaScript:

```
var data = { model, navigationText: this.navText };
```

An object literal is a comma delimited list of `key: value`s, JavaScript won't add `navigationText: this.navText` to the object when you do the above. A bit later you say:

```
data.toJSON()
```

so presumably you want to call `toJSON` on the `model` and then add your `navigationText` key to the result:

```
var data = model.toJSON();
data.navigationText = this.navText;
```

and then hand `data` to the template function:

```
JST['templates/book'](data)
```

You could also restructure the template so that the model data and the extra `navigationText` are kept separate, something like:

```
<%= model.id %>
<%= navigationText %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= id %>
<%= navigationText %>
```

Then you could say:

```
JST['templates/book']({
    model: model.toJSON(),
    navigationText: this.navText
})
```

The big advantage here is that you'd avoid possibly overlaps between the model's attributes and any extra things you want to put in your template.

Comment: When I use: `model: model.toJSON()`, I then have to access the variables in my template like: `model.model.variable`, is there a way not to do this?

Comment: Has something replaced your `toJSON` implementation? What you're seeing is not standard Backbone behavior. I suppose you could use `model.toJSON().model` or similar trickery if necessary.

Comment: i don't know about JST, but in Underscore templates, there is no need to use .toJSON(). You can just call model.get() from within your template.

Comment: @LaurensKling: `JST` should be the pre-compiled version of the templates, they could be Underscore or Handlebars or ... You can pass whole models to the template but cloning the data by calling `toJSON` is a recommended best practice to help keep your templates from accidentally changing your data.